# chef reassigning attributes from another namespace in recipe cause undefined method error in 4 levels array

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have a dependency on community consul cookbook from my cookbook.
 Because I have consul in server and client modes I want to separate namespaces.
In this case, I can use following construction in my recipe:

```
node.default['consul']['config']['server'] = node['consul-server']['config']['server'] if node['consul-server']['config']['server']
node.default['consul']['config']['ui'] = node['consul-server']['config']['ui'] if node['consul-server']['config']['ui']
node.default['consul']['config']['ports']['http'] = node['consul-server']['config']['ports']['http'] if node['consul-server']['config']['ports']['http']
node.default['consul']['config']['ports']['https'] = node['consul-server']['config']['ports']['https'] if node['consul-server']['config']['ports']['https']
```

first two lines forks as expected, but two last lines generating a following error:

```
   ================================================================================
   Recipe Compile Error in /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/eax-consul-cluster/recipes/default.rb
   ================================================================================

   NoMethodError
   -------------
   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

why this happens on same construction and the only difference between them is array one level deeper?

Answer (score 0):

This is because at some level, the `[]` method returns `nil`. For example, suppose `node.default['consul']` returns `nil`, then `node.default['consul']['config']` should raise the error you saw.

If `node.default` is a hash of hashes of hashes of ..., then for reading values, you can try `Hash#dig`, for example:

```
h = {'a' => {'b' => 'c'} }
h.dig('a', 'b')  #=> c
h.dig('x', 'y')  #=> nil
```

For setting values, you have to make sure the parent level has already been set.

Comment: I believe it happens in `if` section, but shouldn't `if` go to `else` in case of nil?

Comment: if the value in condition is `nil` we never have to try to assign this value into the variable in `then` section

Comment: But if `node['consul-server']['config']['ports']` is `nil`, what will happen? You're calling `node['consul-server']['config']['ports']['http']`, which is `nil['http']`, and that will definitely throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Switch that to `if if node.read('consul-server', 'config', 'ports', 'http')`. That automatically checks for `nil` in intervening keys in a similar way to `Hash#dig`.

Comment: Since `chef` appears to be your specialty and you stated "we" below I am going to assume you have something to do with development. Can you please explain why one would not offer a `deep_merge` for this type of thing ( I saw one is offered as a mixin but why is it not mixed into `Mash`)? Additionally are there objections to implementing one as I have? I don't use chef but ruby is ruby and the original code posted does not need that many conditionals in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

On a side note since your naming conventions line up exactly below the first level merging them seems more appropriate and avoids all the conditionals, depth checking, etc.

For Example:

```
# Essentially a railsesque #deep_merge!
merge_proc = Proc.new do |_k,old,new|
   if old.is_a?(Hash) && new.is_a?(Hash)
     old.merge(new,&merge_proc)
   else
     new
   end
end

node.default['consul'].merge!(node['consul-server'], &merge_proc)
```

[`Hash#merge!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) because a `Mash` (Chef's subclass of a `Hash`) is still a `Hash`